# How to implement a informming messages in application like kivy?

Tags: android, python, sockets, kivy

In facebook and some messaging apps, when we have messages from somebody we get the message "received message".

This tells us every time when we have received message.

(I'll develop this app in android with kivy)

Question is=

1. How can a application notice when received a message? Is the process is running even its closed? or is it still running while its window is closed
2. What kind of Kivy API will help to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to call the relevant part of the android api using pyjnius (which lets you do so from python).

The easiest way for this particular task is to use [plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer), which abstracts platform specific apis to a pythonic interface. It already supports notifications, and you can check the source to see how it works.